# Get TLS version from the client(browser) that makes request to tomcat server

Tags: ssl, tomcat, tomcat8, tls1.2

I have java app deployed to tomcat server 8.5.32.

I configured the server to use only TLS 1.2 so if the user send a request to the app(tomcat server) using browser and the browser is old(supports only TLS 1.0 and TLS 1.1) then i want to know that someone tries to reach my app but no handshake is made and I want to make a record in DB.

Is there any way I can know that client is using TLS version that my server is not supporting it and somehow get that info what is the TLS version of the client? OR at least to know that client is using older TLS version?

Comment: I doubt this is possible without writing your own Connnector.

Comment: @user207421 The dirty solution is to use `-Djavax.net.debug=all` and parse the long log output looking for handshake failures and find what was sent before, then use an external program to insert the data in DB. Heavy and not perfect when there is much traffic and the log overlaps. Nothing built-in in Tomcat or JSSE, or openssl.

Comment: @EugèneAdell So, you are saying that the only way that i can get that information is to look into tomcat log?

Comment: Without adding any other component in your architecture, that's the only solution that I know. This will give you a ton of logs, see [Debugging SSL/TLS Connections](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/jsse/ReadDebug.html) to have an overview. Adding a component such as BIG-IP LTM and offloading SSL on it would give you all the details (how many failures/success, TLS version, cipher used,..), but that's not what you were asking strictly.

Comment: @EugèneAdell Ok, i see that there is no easy way to do this. i am wondering if there is a way to configure tomcat to redirect the users to some custom jsp page with a message like ->please update your browser version..., when SSL/TLS Handshake Failed?

Comment: If you can't handle the traffic, you also can't redirect it. A cheap component that you can add is an Apache HTTP in front of Tomcat, and configure it to specifically handle the lower versions that Tomcat is not configured for.

Comment: @EugèneAdell I want to ask you another question. Right now my server is supporting TLS 1.0 1.1 and 1.2.So lets say browser is using TLS1.0, no handshake failure everything is working. Is there a way to get the information from the request object or some other object what TLS version the browser is using or this info is found also just in the logs?

Comment: Unluckily [HttpServletRequest](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html) doesn't implement this. The only way I'm thinking about, is using a set of rewrite rules from the [Rewrite Valve](https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.5-doc/rewrite.html) as this one allows conditions on `%{SSL:variable}` . You would then redirect the browser to a dedicated URL (one URL by protocol version, or as a parameter). It'll take some time to write but it should work.